# keyCode if/else commands

Tags: java, android, voice

I have google voice recognition integrated into my project.  With the google voice recognition their is block of code you must write, inside of that block of code you are suppose to put the code for each command, for whatever the user says.

So I have whatever the user says printing to a `textview`, so I thought about creating a if/else statement.

```
 if textview == "rotate" {
rotate the image code }
```

But then I run into a few warnings saying `textview` can not do `==`, so then I changed it to `.equals`. And after changing it, it still runs into the same warning, `.equals` cannot run on a textview.

Here is the log on the emulator

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH (has extras) }
```

On an actual device it will run and not crash.  But none of the else/if statements will run.

Then I changed the `textview` into a `edittext` and ran into same errors.

Is their a easier way of doing it for google voice recognition?

Or is this the right way?  And how can i get it run?

Comment: Is the textview updating per the users speech? Is the actual issue just that the if clauses aren't working?

Comment: Yes, the textview updates every-time the user says something. So at the beginning it is empty then if the user says something it will display on the textview.

Comment: the if clauses isn't running.  Like in the question above, if i have a if statement, that shows textview == "rotate" and if the textview says rotate, the code isn't running.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the text value of the TextView before you can use it in your IF clause. When comparing strings always use .equals and not ==. == compares that the two objects are identical and when we are comparing strings this is not what we want. However, back to your error. You were trying to compare the actual textview and not the contents of the Textview. You can't use .equals to compare a textview object.

```
if(textview.getText().equals("rotate"){
      //Do your logic here. 
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That worked! I just stared programming and learning java. So i am running into a few speed bumps.

Comment: @fafafa no worries :)